# takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given error however it does take 2

Tags: python

I am getting an error saying a a function doesn't take 2 arguments, but it does.

My code:

```
def update(coin, fiat):
        coinone.set(f"{coin} is worth {fiat}")
```

The error:

```
 line 29, in cont
    update(coin, fiat)
TypeError: update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

edit: The function which is being used cannot use data from other classes without using global variables.

Comment: If you have a stale `.pyc` lying around, you may be running an older version of the code, where `update` does indeed take only a single argument, but the error message is constructed using the newer `.py` file.

Comment: plz share more details... insufficient  info..

Comment: Wrong "update" function? Call "print(update)" directly after defining "update" and before the line with error. It should print the same twice, especially the hex address after "at".

Comment: I suspect you have redefined `update` elsewhere in your code and line 29 is calling the version you don't intend. Temporarily change the call to have one parameter and see what happens.

Comment: @chepner Do you know what would cause Python to use an old `.pyc` instead of generating a new one?

Comment: One way would be to edit the file, but not reload the module or restart the interpreter before calling `update` again.